# Fix so that when I reload child page I stay on it instead of being redirected to parent page (vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have created dynamic child URL for our guide but when I refresh the page it seems to be
loading the parent page instead of the page I am currently on.

For example:
Let's say that I am on the page [www.mywebsite.com/guide/bike](http://www.mywebsite.com/guide/bike) and I reload the page.
Then in the URL it still says [www.mywebsite.com/guide/bike](http://www.mywebsite.com/guide/bike) but the content of the page is the content of the page [www.mywebsite.com/guide](http://www.mywebsite.com/guide)

How can I make sure that if I reload a child page to [www.mywebsite.com/guide/](http://www.mywebsite.com/guide/) that I then stay on that page and am not redirected to [www.mywebsite.com/guide/](http://www.mywebsite.com/guide/) ?

My code in the router/index.js file for the guide path is:

```
const routes =[
       {
        path: '/guide/:category?',
        name: 'guide',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "guide" */ '../views/guidetemplate.vue'),
        children: [
            {
               path: '',
               name: 'GuideHome',
               component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "guide" */ '../views/guide.vue'),
            },
            {
              path: '/',
              name: 'guidesub',
              component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "analytic" */ '../views/guide_subcategory.vue'),
              props:true
            },
          ]
      },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode:'history',
  routes
})
export default router
```

Then I have a guidetemplate file

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
</style>
```

I also have a guide.vue file with contains the menu and general information of the guide, ex [www.mywebsite.com/guide/](http://www.mywebsite.com/guide/)

Then I have the guide_subcategory.vue file which contains the information for the child page (ex [www.mywebsite.com/guide/bike](http://www.mywebsite.com/guide/bike)

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="">

      <div :style="{width:'80%',marginTop:'2%',marginLeft:'6%', height:'200px',paddingBottom:'30px'}" >

        <h1 :style="{fontSize:'26px',fontWeight:'bold',textAlign:'left'}">
            {{this.name}}
        </h1> 
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props:['category'],
  data:function(){
    return{
      id:0,
      guides:[],
      name:"",
    }
  },
  methods:{
    run(){
      if (this.category=='bike'){
        this.id=0
      }else if (this.category=='phone') {
        this.id=1
      }else if (this.category=='computer') {
        this.id=2
      }
      else{
        this.id=3
      }
    }
  },
  watch:{
    "$route.params.id"(){
      this.run()
    }
  },
  mounted(){

    this.run()


    this.guides = [
      {
        "id":0,
        "name":"Bike ",
      },
      {
        "id":1,
        "name":"Phone ",
      },
      {
        "id":2,
        "name":"Computer",
      },
    ]

    this.name =this.guides[this.id].name
  }

}
</script>
```

The "watch" function was an attempt to solve the problem but didn't do so.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Watch for the property router param `category` not `id`.